# forn send post with hidden <input> value doesn't work in controller

Tags: controller, hidden

i'm trying send to hidden input value to controller.
but when receiving the data from the controller as reqeust.getparameter("")
The previous data is put and comes.
Does request.getparameger data remain in cookie form?
How can I solve this?

this is my js code :

```js
function onCreatePDF(ctx,e_Id,t_Id,t_name){
   $('#cover').show();
    var imgStr='';
    var imgStr='';
  let element = document.getElementById("chart")
  if(element){
    var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();
      chart.exportImage().done(function(data) {
    
      var b64Img  = btoa(data);
        var form = $("<form></form>");
       form.attr("id","createPDF");
       form.attr("action",ctx+"/executeReportToPdf_new");
       form.attr("method","post");
       form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'b64_image', value:b64Img }));
       form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'e_id', value:e_Id }));
       form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 't_id', value:t_Id }));
       form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 't_name', value:t_name }));
            form.appendTo('body');
}
$("#createPDF").submit();
            $('#cover').hide();
         });
    }
}
```

this is my controller code :

```js
 
@RequestMapping(value="/executeReportToPdf_new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public synchronized ModelAndView executeReportToPdf_new(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        Map<String, Object>param = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        param.put("exec_tc_id",request.getParameter("e_id"));
        param.put("testcase_id",request.getParameter("t_id"));
        param.put("tcName",request.getParameter("t_name"));
  
 // previous data is displayed in LOG.
```

Comment: Could we the issue with the browser, some browser eg. Safari doesn't allow to send data from the hidden fields

Comment: no issue with the browser. If the data passed from javascript is normal data.
but data received as a request from the controller is output to the previously transferred data log.